# Are the questions on this site only for IT workers and programmers?

Tags: discussion

Not sure if this is the right place to ask (if not, please move it elsewhere so it can be answered).

I have seen some really great questions on this forum, but many of the answers seem specific only to people working in the IT world or are programmers.

I find this to be a bit restrictive.

Is there a reason for this?

Are there any sites for all professions in general?

Comment: This is close to the right place, this question is more likely to be moved to meta.workplace, we can get that done for you now though, so don't worry if it is closed for migration!

Comment: We actually need *more* questions from non-IT workers!

Comment: IT works post on here as I think we have the easiest access to computers to skive off and check it :P

Comment: I would say that the reasons so many questions are about IT and programming are largely historical: one of the main driving forces behind the creation of this site was to provide a home for all the workplace-related questions on the [Programmers' StackExchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/). As Jim G said, we need more questions from other fields!!

Comment: @Carson Also the fact that the StackExchange network started with StackOverflow.

Comment: Just one thing... WE ARE NOT A FORUM - This is a Q&A site where people can ask questions and get answers to those questions with out the typical chatter that occurs on a forum.

Answer (score 13):

This site is the correct please to come and ask workplace related questions.

You have correctly identified that a large amount of our current questions and answers are mostly programmer-centric. This isn't because everything else is not on topic though, this is predominantly because the community we have here is largely comprised of programmers!

As long as your question is about problems faced in the workplace, isn't overly broad, and isn't solely a personal issue then it is likely to be on topic here, if you are unsure you can always ask in Chat (requires 50 rep) or on [meta.workplace](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/) for clarification.

We also have a useful [help page](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help) that might be worth you checking out to get familiar with our limitations here.

Welcome to the site!